# Interface or API to retrieve power consumption data for built-in devices in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, daemon, power-management

I need to write a power, temperature monitor system for linux system. It needs display some power statistics for for some or all builtin-devices as what powerTop does.I have searched quite a bit and I'm still clueless. Could some one give me a guidance.

Comment: Please give more specifics about the platform.  Also see the [power documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/power/00-INDEX).  If you have *hardware*, you can measure supply currents and voltages.  If you do not have this hardware, you must guess.  The same for temperature; so only if you give a clue as to hardware, can someone answer.

Comment: It should be generic to any Linux machine.

Comment: Then it is impossible.  You need hardware support.  Some chips present the same interface to the CPU but have different power profiles.  There is no way to generically estimate either.  *lmsensor* and */sys/power* will be present if there is hardware support.

Answer (score 1):

For measuring the temperature you might use the [lm_sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/) tool.
For power consumption take a look at the [acpi client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acpiclient/). Both should be available for most distributions.

You can use these tools to determine the required values and display them in your software.

Example output of lm_sensors:

```
pc87366-isa-6620
Adapter: ISA adapter
VCORE:       +2.01 V  (min =  +1.90 V, max =  +2.10 V)
VCC:         +4.99 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.03 V)
VPWR:       +11.88 V  (min =  +5.93 V, max = +28.02 V)
+12V:       +11.93 V  (min = +11.02 V, max = +13.01 V)
-12V:       -12.19 V  (min = -13.10 V, max = -11.06 V)
GND:         +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
Vsb:         +3.28 V  (min =  +3.00 V, max =  +3.59 V)
Vdd:         +3.28 V  (min =  +3.00 V, max =  +3.59 V)
Vbat:        +3.01 V  (min =  +2.40 V, max =  +3.01 V)
AVdd:        +3.26 V  (min =  +3.00 V, max =  +3.59 V)
Temp:        +55.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high = +70.0°C)  
                      (crit = +85.0°C)
```

If you do not get certain values you might have to tweak your configuration. Look at the following locations (text has been taken from the man page):

> ```
> /etc/sensors3.conf
> /etc/sensors.conf
>       The system-wide libsensors(3) configuration file. /etc/sensors3.conf  is  tried  first,
>       and if it doesn't exist, /etc/sensors.conf is used instead.
>
> /etc/sensors.d
>       A  directory  where you can put additional libsensors configuration files.  Files found
>       in this directory will be processed in alphabetical order after the default  configura‐
>       tion file. Files with names that start with a dot are ignored.
> ```

Comment: I don't understand why lm_sensors didn't give voltage readings?

Comment: I just updated my answer; make sure that you have hardware support for the values you want to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write something completely on your own you may have a look at [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface), which features are provided via [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).

```
ls /sys/power
```

should give you a first look at the information exported.